# How to solve this sum with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum _{i=1}^{n-k+1}\frac{\left(n-k\right)!\left(n-i\right)!}{\left(n-k-i\right)!}
$$

I dont know how to solve this sum with factorials.

Comment: Are $n$ and $k$ both fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Since $n$ and $k$ are both constants, let’s let $m=n-k$ and rewrite it in the visually simpler form

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\frac{m!(m+k-i)!}{(m-i)!}\,.$$

The denominator is negative when $i=m+1$, so we might as well lower the upper limit to $m$ and make it

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{m!(m+k-i)!}{(m-i)!}\,.$$

As $i$ runs from $1$ up to $m$, $m-i$ runs from $m-1$ down to $0$. And $m-i$ appears in two of the three factorials, so let’s let $j=m-i$: with that substitution it becomes

$$\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{m!(k+j)!}{j!}=m!\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\frac{(k+j)!}{j!}\,.$$

The fraction inside the summation looks like part of a binomial coefficient:

$$\binom{k+j}j=\frac{(k+j)!}{j!k!}\,,$$

so

$$\frac{(k+j)!}{j!}=k!\binom{k+j}j\,,$$

and the sum can be rewritten as

$$m!k!\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{k+j}j=k!(n-k)!\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{k+j}j\,.$$

This last summation is a form of the [hockey stick identity](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eehallman/math55/homework9-sols.pdf) [PDF], and with that I’ll let you finish off the simplification.

**Added:** By the way, I was writing this as I thought my way through the solution, so this write-up very closely mirrors my actual thought processes, and you can take it as an illustration of how one might actually think about attacking such a problem.